# Will the IRS seize My refund if my dependant has child support arrears?

Tags: united-states, taxes, refund, dependents

My adult son is now disabled and lives with me. His child support is in arrears, but half of his SSDI is garnished for child support. Will the IRS take my refund if I claim him as a dependent?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think they would. The only reason to garnish wages or refunds or whatever would be to ensure the child support does get paid to the custodial parent, right?

Comment: (I keep meaning to look up why "garnish" is the verb used for that action...)

Comment: That's the original meaning. The idea of gathering or collecting went in two directions: gathering what was owed and gathering to decorate. Eventually the latter sense provided a noun meaning the stuff that was gathered for decorations as well.

Comment: @keshlam That doesn't appear to be the situation. It seems the _adult_ son has a child, and support obligations of that child. That's why _his_ SSDI is being taken.

Comment: Ah. Sorry; I did misread the question. I think the answer is that the IRS won't go after Mom's return, but may set its sights on the son's. And of course the child's caretaker (mother or other) can go after him in court to demand those payments.